# How to get all elements at mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseevent

I have many elements on the same position and I want to listen for hover event on every element behind even if they are behind other elements, is there a way I can do this?
(They are not hierarchically related and sometimes they are circles, polygons, etc, so checking for bounding rect is not ok)

[**http://jsfiddle.net/4NdNS/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NdNS/4/)

```
$circles.on("mouseover",function(){console.log(this);});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xWDE/5/)**

html:

```
<div id=response></div>
<svg id="mycircle Area">
    <circle  id="C1" fill="none" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle fill="none" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle fill="none" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
</svg>
```

jq:

```
$('circle').on("mousedown",function(e){
   $("#response").append($(e).attr('id')+' ');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

css:

```
circle{
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

---

this is your edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xWDE/5/)

Comment: on circle click it should append three times "click", one for every element at the mouse position even if they are behind other elements.

Comment: answer updated, after your question has been updated, try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/5xWDE/5/ it's working

Comment: try this : `$('circle').on`

Comment: you want to trig the circles only ?

Comment: if you want to trigg the circles only, then try this : http://jsfiddle.net/5xWDE/19/ if it's correct let me know, to update my answer.

Comment: No, it's still incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/5xWDE/21/ this only triggers on the top element, three times.

Comment: this trigg all http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/5xWDE/22/ and you should manage it with parent object for multiple group circles.

Comment: this is supposed to trigger click circles on the mouse position only.